# gnuMake, how to force a phony target to run more than once?

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

my build system insists on executing make with all the targets in one call, so i get:

`make clean test clean build`

the second clean will just say "Nothing to be done for `clean'." even though it's added to the .PHONY target.

any way around that?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: maybe, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Beta basically i have a phony step to create some data files (basically it concatenate some files and run a template engine to fill some gaps) then i run the tests, then i clean up everything and run that data file step again as the last step to actually package the software... the company uses hudson jobs. I think i will just trigger a new for the packaging step after the first one does the test. Was trying to avoid that as it too expensive (in time) to create a new VM and all that... or maybe i will just duplicate the work for that phony target twice (it's 2lines in the make file after all)

Comment: Are you sure that the `test` step modifies the data files? If it does, you should probably reconsider your design; if it doesn't, there's no need to rebuild them. That said, the easiest way is probably to duplicate the commands that build them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yuk! Do *not* do this. Do not rely on implicit ordering of targets—it changes completely when you use `make -j`. Make your ordering *explicit*. If you really must clean between builds, then something like:

```
.PHONY: everything
everything:
    ${MAKE} clean
    ${MAKE} test
    ${MAKE} clean
    ${MAKE} build
```

Again, the recursive make is rather smelly, but is your best option in this case.

Comment: i have control over -j on this environment, but this is a very good think to keep in mind.

Comment: @gcb `-j` is the whole point of make imho, and a good test that your makefiles are correct

Answer (score 5):

I verified this one. Try this:

```
test: ...
    ...

build: ...
    ...

clean%: ...
    ...
```

Then you can call:

```
make clean1 test clean2 build
```

Seems as long as the target name is different, even it hits the same target pattern, it will rerun it.

Comment: Sadly, it breaks completely when you use parallel _make_ (which is kind of the whole point of _make_ IMHO).